# Overwrite first n elements of an array?

Tags: ruby

Here's my scenario:

```
a = ["","","","","","","","","",""]  #10 elements. Need not always be blank.
b = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I want to modify `a` such that the first `n` elements of `a` are replaced with the elements of `b` where `n = b.size()`:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","","","","","",""]
```

So, is there something simple like `a.replace(b)` minus the truncation?

An alternative would be a way to append `a.size() - b.size()` number of elements to `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use slicing:

```
a[0, 4] = b
```

or with a dynamic length:

```
a[0, b.length] = b
```